# Regular Expression for number

Tags: regex

Please help me to make a Regular Expression with following rule -

1. Max number can be 9999.99
2. Should be non-negative
3. Can not be 0, but 0.01 and so on is valid
4. So, I need a non negative number between 0.01-9999.99

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Erm, this isn't really a job for Regexp, but it works with it anyway:

```
/(\d{2,4}(\.(\d[1-9])|([1-9]\d))?)|[1-9]/
```

A More strict evaluation would be:

```
/^([1-9]\d{,3}(\.\d{1,2})?)?|(0\.([1-9]\d?)|(0\.0[1-9]))$/
```

With not accepting leading zero's, but allowing for just one decimal: "0.1".
Bear in mind, decimals are optional.

I suggest, however, to use mathematical operations: Convert to float and then check:

```
if((num > 0) && (num < 100000)) {...}
```

You can use `sprintf()` to get the representation that you need, for instance limiting the number of decimals, etc.

Comment: +1 for making the period and decimal part optional -- the OP didn't specify it, but without that, an input like "100" would fail. +1 for saying Regex is the wrong tool for parsing numbers!

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. I need a regular expression because number should have maximum two digits after decimal. So, 9.9999 is invalid though it is in between 0-10000

Comment: Also, the expression you have given is not working as expected.

Comment: It's PCRE, you need to tailor it to your Regexp-Dialekt.

Comment: I converted this to ^(\d{2,4}(\.(\d[1-9])|([1-9]\d))?)|[1-9]$
But its allowing multiple zero.

Comment: I agree that numerical comparisons are the best way to handle this, but the regex you gave is really not correct. The last alternative (`[0-9]`) will match *any* string with a digit in it because you didn't anchor it. If you do anchor this regex, it won't match single digit floats (eg: `1.9`) which the OP wants to accept.

Comment: I did, some changes to the answer. In case you need a more specific match, restate your question.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need a regular expression to do this? Just convert your string to a double and check if it's between 0.01 and 9999.99.

Answer (score 0):

As people have already answered, you can get digits fairly easily by using [0-9] or \d.  By using {min,max} you can specify how many of a character or character set to get for a match.

Here's a good reference: http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html