# Amount validation - regular expression in Java

Tags: java, expression

In java class I need regular expression for amount validation with the following conditions:

1. Maximum price is 9999.99
2. Minimum amount is 1
3. Decimal values is optional (Paise is optional) that is 9999 is Valid

I write the following regular expression but it always `return false` for both valid and invalid inputs.

Here's example:

```
private static final String PRICE_PATTERN = "((/d{1,4})(((//.)(/d{0,2})){0,1}))";

public PriceCheck() {
    pattern = Pattern.compile(PRICE_PATTERN);
}

public boolean validate(final String username) {
    matcher = pattern.matcher(username);
    return matcher.matches();  // always return false;
}
```

Comment: any reason why you don't parse double and check the values?

Comment: Sounds like a homework assignment, hence the odd requirement @x4rf41.

Comment: It also seems that the decimal place is required as written.  Or maybe I'm just confused by the (potentially) overused parenthesis.  Remember the `|` (or) operator!

Comment: This has already been answered here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561782/regular-expression-for-number/3561788#3561788. In addition for checking for values all you will need is to make sure that the number of characters after the decimal place is not more than 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this expression instead:

```
private static final String PRICE_PATTERN = "((\\d{1,4})(((\\.)(\\d{0,2})){0,1}))";
```